# How to check if Option Button exists on sheet?

Tags: excel, vba, radio-button

I have a workbook with multiple sheets where I use **option buttons** for different scripts to be active.

Not all of the buttons are used on all of the sheets. They are written in a single sub, so if I do not use an option button on a sheet, the `Set shp` will give me an error because it doesn't find the button, unless I use the `On Error Resume Next`.

How could I get rid of the `On Error Resume Next`? I thought of something like check if the **option button** is there and use `Set shp` only if the button is present on the sheet but I can not get it working.

```
Private Sub ob(opt As String)
    Dim shp1 As Shape
    Dim shp2 As Shape
    Dim shp3 As Shape
    Dim shp4 As Shape
    Dim shp5 As Shape

    On Error Resume Next ' <-I want to get rid of this
    Set shp1 = ActiveSheet.Shapes("OptionButton1")
    Set shp2 = ActiveSheet.Shapes("OptionButton2")
    Set shp3 = ActiveSheet.Shapes("OptionButton3")
    Set shp4 = ActiveSheet.Shapes("OptionButton4")
    Set shp5 = ActiveSheet.Shapes("OptionButton5")

    Select Case xlOn
        Case shp1.ControlFormat.Value
            opt = "ob1"
        Case shp2.ControlFormat.Value
            opt = "ob2"
        Case shp3.ControlFormat.Value
            opt = "ob3"
        Case shp4.ControlFormat.Value
            opt = "ob4"
        Case shp5.ControlFormat.Value
            opt = "ob5"
    End Select

End Sub
```

EDIT:

The actual script looks like this after Ralph's version:

```
Private Sub ob(opt As String)
    Dim shp1 As Shape
    Dim shp2 As Shape
    Dim shp3 As Shape
    Dim shp4 As Shape
    Dim shp5 As Shape        

For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
    For Each shp In Worksheets(ws.Name).Buttons
        Select Case btn.Name
            Case "OptionButton1"
                Set shp1 = ActiveSheet.Shapes("OptionButton1")
            Case "OptionButton2"
                Set shp2 = ActiveSheet.Shapes("OptionButton2")
            Case "OptionButton3"
                Set shp3 = ActiveSheet.Shapes("OptionButton3")
            Case "OptionButton4"
                Set shp4 = ActiveSheet.Shapes("OptionButton4")
            Case "OptionButton5"
                Set shp5 = ActiveSheet.Shapes("OptionButton5")
        End Select
    Next shp
Next ws

Select Case xlOn
    Case shp1.ControlFormat.Value
        opt = "ob1"
    Case shp2.ControlFormat.Value
        opt = "ob2"
    Case shp3.ControlFormat.Value
        opt = "ob3"
    Case shp4.ControlFormat.Value
        opt = "ob4"
    Case shp5.ControlFormat.Value
        opt = "ob5"
End Select

End Sub
```

I get the object required error on line:

```
Select Case btn.Name
```

Comment: I'm thinking that a better approach would be using `ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range(...)` to grab the shapes you want into a collection, then iterate over them until you get your desired return value. It's pretty much an entire rewrite of your code though, I'll have crack at it during my lunch break if no-one's proposed a better solution before then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest this approach. Hope it helps:

```
Public Sub AllShapesOnAllSheets()
For Each btn In ActiveSheet.OptionButtons
Select Case btn.Name
    Case "OptionButton1"
        If btn.Value = xlOn Then opt = "ob1"
    Case "OptionButton2"
        If btn.Value = xlOn Then opt = "ob2"
    Case "OptionButton3"
        If btn.Value = xlOn Then opt = "ob3"
    Case "OptionButton4"
        If btn.Value = xlOn Then opt = "ob4"
    Case "OptionButton5"
        If btn.Value = xlOn Then opt = "ob5"
End Select
Next btn
End Sub
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question asked and I'm also pretty sure that the Worksheet object doesn't have a method/property named Buttons (at least in my version of Excel it doesn't).

Comment: [This MSDN page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff841127.aspx) lists all events, methods and properties that are part of the `Worksheet` object. I don't see `Buttons` on that list anywhere. If you've got some proof that this property exists then by all means enlighten me.

Comment: If you're working with VB.NET maybe. The page you linked shows that .Buttons is a method available in the interop library, not native VBA. The question is tagged as VBA so answers should be _in_ VBA.

Comment: Even if I accept that `Worksheet.Buttons` exists then your code _still_ doesn't actually answer the question being asked. All you're doing is iterating through all the buttons in all the worksheets, which isn't even a requirement in the stated problem. You've still got a way to go before this is a helpful answer. I'd also appreciate it if you didn't link my profile in your answer, it has absolutely no relevance since your answer should stand on its own without supporting information (not that a link to my profile is even supporting info to begin with).

Comment: Aiken: The Buttons-Class can be found within the VBA Object Explorer: just go to the object explorer (pressing F2) in VBA, right-click into the window and select "Show Hidden Members". There you will find the Buttons- and the Button-Class.

Comment: so can I start inserting this into my script, or I have no chance that this will work?

Comment: Well, obviously you still have to check for the .Value and you'll have to complete the code where I took the short-cut with [...]. But other than that I am pretty confident it will work.

Comment: My bad. There was a typo in my solution. Of course, it should be coherent throughout the script. Either use shp everywhere or btn. Also, my original script used the Buttons-Class when you needed the OptionButtons-Class. I just updated the solution. It works in my Excel.

Comment: The script does not work. "The item with the specified name wasn't found" error on line **Set shp3 = ActiveSheet.Shapes("OptionButton3")** when the button is missing, also when I added the **On Error Resume Next**, and checked what is going on with msgbox, when  **"OptionButton1"** was selected, it has set the value of **opt** to **"ob3"** 2 times. I think because of there are 2 buttons on that sheet. 1 and 2

Comment: In fact you may remove all these set shpx... they are redundant and no longer needed. Yet, it is strange that (apparently) your code found an OptionButton with the name "OptionButton1" (must be due to the select case...statement) but when your are trying to do something with it, VBE says it cannot be found. Seems almost impossible!

Comment: ok, the actual question was if we can avoid this somehow, or is it impossible? This way we just made stuff more complicated than the original solution.

Comment: More complicated? Not sure what you mean by that. It seems to me (personally) that my proposition is much shorter: one case statement eliminated, all dim statements gone. Looking back at the original question you wanted to eliminate the "on error resume next" which I propose to eliminate by cycling through all existing (!) OptionButtons within your Excel file. So, is the code working or do you experience any problems?

Comment: As I mentioned before, the code is not working. Could not eliminate the "on error resume next" and even by using it, the opt string gets different value than it should.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/71773/discussion-between-ralph-and-divin3).

Comment: The last edit works flawlessly. I voted up and I accept the answer.